# Translate PHP preg_replace to javascript and set it recursive

Tags: javascript, php, preg-replace, str-replace

Hi i have this simple code:

```
 preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '</br>',$string);
```

i would like to replicate the same codein JS so i do:

```
string.replace('/[\r\n]+/','</br>');
```

but this won't work.

Also i would like to make it recursive using `g` , is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace()` accepts a first parameter of type `RegExp` and you are passing a string, you need to change to:

```
string.replace(/[\r\n]+/,'</br>');
```

Also, `replace()` isn't a static method, in other words you don't call it like this. Instead you call it on the string on which you want to perform the replacement.

If you want to use `g` then you can:

```
string.replace(/[\r\n]+/g,'</br>');
                        ^
```

Comment: I assume he was calling it on a variable called `string`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Maybe, that is left to the OP to answer.

Comment: sorry what's the differences between your code and mine? i'm blinded? :D

Comment: @sbaaaang: No quotes around the regex ;-)

Comment: @sbaaaang: That's `Swiffer` :-P

Comment: ahahahahahahahah what a mistake sorry %) i'm done for today need to go bed yep yep yep :D

Comment: @Sniffer i removed my comment i called you Duster like the Swiffer but damn i confused Swiffer with Sniffer , sorry :D was just a joke :D you're welcome! and thnk you a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `.replace` supports both strings and regexes as what to replace.  You sent it a string, it doesn't know it's a regex.  It was looking for the *literal string* `'/[\r\n]+/'`.

You need to use a regex literal:

```
string.replace(/[\r\n]+/g,'</br>');
```

Yes, you can use use regexes like that, with no quotes!

You can use the `new RegExp` constructor if you want to use a string as your regex:

```
string.replace(new RegExp('/[\r\n]+/', 'g'),'</br>');
```

Comment: sorry i just accepted the most voted one, since i think both answers were awesome! thank you man!

Comment: @sbaaaang: Pick whichever one helped you the most :-)